# Excel if blank cell use different cell in formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using the formula: `=(YEAR(K3)-YEAR(I3))*12+MONTH(K3)-MONTH(I3)` to calculate the number of months between two dates however if the cell in *I3* is blank I want it to use the calculation `=(YEAR(K3)-YEAR(G3))*12+MONTH(K3)-MONTH(G3)` instead?

Can anyone suggest a formula to do this?

Many thanks :)

Comment: just need to put them together: `=IF(I3="",` `(YEAR(K3)-YEAR(G3))*12+MONTH(K3)-MONTH(G3)` `,` `(YEAR(K3)-YEAR(I3))*12+MONTH(K3)-MONTH(I3)` `)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ISBLANK` to check if I3 contains a value:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I3),(YEAR(K3)-YEAR(G3))*12+MONTH(K3)-MONTH(G3),(YEAR(K3)-YEAR(I3))*12+MONTH(K3)-MONTH(I3)))
```

`ISBLANK` returns TRUE when the cell is empty, and FALSE when it isn't .